# Bigger tolerance ellipses in paired scatterplot

Tags: r, statistics, correlation, scatter-plot, normal-distribution

I'm running some normality tests on the `iris` data in R. One of the things I'd like to do is to create a `pairs` plot (scatterplots of variable pairs) for the `setosa` species, *and draw a tolerance ellipse around each scatterplot cloud*. Currently, what I have is:

```
library(psych)

X <- iris
X1 <- subset(X, Species == "setosa")[,1:4]

#pairs(X, pch=19)      # This is basic.
psych::pairs.panels(X,
    method="pearson",  # We're going to display correlations above the diagonal, not scatterplots.
    density = TRUE,    # show histograms
    ellipses = TRUE,   # show correlation ellipses
    lm = TRUE,         # Normally there are non-linear fits drawn through the data. Make them lines instead.
)
```

This produces the following plot:
[image: pairs plot]

As you can see, the ellipses are drawn, but they wrap around very few data points. In a function like `car::ellipse`, there is an option to select a (Mahalanobis) `radius` for the ellipse, which is about 3 for a 99%-tolerance ellipse. I would like the same thing here, but sadly, `psych::pairs.panels` [has no radius option](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/psych/versions/2.2.9/topics/pairs.panels). How do I get bigger ellipses?

Comment: What happens when you decrease alpha?

Comment: @IRTFM As per your username (`;-)`), I had already read the docs to try that. It doesn't do anything for me because `alpha` is about the confidence intervals you can enable with the option `ci=TRUE`. It is not about the ellipses.

Comment: Yeah. I discovered that. I took a crack at modifying the code but didn’t succeed. Why don’t you look at one of the other packages that draws ellipses?

Comment: @IRTFM Just ellipses, or the scatterplots too? I know how to draw `car::ellipse` on a single bivariate plot where I know the covariance matrix, but `psych::pairs.panels` hides both the covariance calculations as well as the interface to each separate plot, so even if I could draw ellipses, I would need to know how to apply said method to each subplot.